# What does "grade itself on the percentage of the thousand" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Gigster CEO Roger Dickey told Business Insider the company **graded itself on the percentage of the thousand or so** tech workers on its marketplace who are making a full-time living from work they get through the site. Right now, the proportion is somewhere between 20% and 30%. The company is aiming to get that above 30% by the end of the year and 50% by the end of next year.

http://uk.businessinsider.com/gigster-20-million-redpoint-ventures-marc-benioff-michael-jordan-2017-8

Comment: You should probably reconsider your answer acceptance. The currently-accepted answer is not correct.

Comment: If I had known which one was the correct answer, I'd not have put a question here.

Comment: Good news! The site is designed to *tell* you. Look at the answers' scores! One of them has 3 downvotes and no upvotes. The other one has 4 upvotes and no downvotes. If you can't tell which one helped you, don't accept either one, but in that case, you should trust the higher-scored answer more anyway.

Comment: OK, I did what you told me to.

Answer (score 4):

"The thousand or so tech workers on its marketplace who are making a full-time living from work they get through the site"

is a noun phrase. "thousand or so" means "approximately 1000".

> How many people were in the room?
>   --I don't know, a hundred or so, I suppose.

The approximately 1000 tech workers who...

The ratio of a successful subgroup working full time to the total number of members is the metric the company is using to measure its success.

If the approximately 1000 tech workers represent the total membership, then 1000 is the denominator and the numerator is unstated but can be derived from the 20% and 30% figures in the next sentence. 200 to 300 of the 1000 are full-time.

If the approximately 1000 tech workers represent the successful subgroup, then the denominator is unstated  but can be derived from the 20% and 30% figures in the next sentence.